# Is it usual for finished PhD students to send out physical copies of their thesis to unknown persons?

Tags: thesis, graduation, etiquette

Some time ago, a recently-graduated PhD has sent me a physical (book) copy of his dissertation. The graduate works in a somewhat-related field, but is personally entirely unknown to me (I have some loose connections to the advisor, though). I was reasonably confused by this - I personally have never heard of a custom of sending physical theses to anybody besides maybe parents. I was 100% convinced that I received the dissertation in error (also because the mailing was addressed to my name, but using a wrong department name).

Last week I by chance got hold of the graduate and told him that he sent me his thesis by accident, and asked whether he wants to have it back. He seemed confused and a little bit annoyed that I wanted to give his thesis back - it turns out he actually sent me the book on purpose, assuming that I would be interested in his work. **He told me that he thought it is customary to send a finished PhD thesis to people that he thought might profit from its results.**

**So, is this a thing, at least in some fields? If so, why not just send the core papers or a link to a digital version of the thesis?** Mailing out printed copies seems extremely expensive, and also (at least for me) very unlikely to result in anything else than me having another book gathering dust in my office shelf. I am honestly very unlikely to read an entire thesis, *especially* if I only have it in a dead-tree book version.

Comment: Customary or not, you are certainly under no obligation to do anything with an unsolicited manuscript. Including returning it. Or even acknowledging it, though a quick "got it, will have no chance to look at it any time soon but thanks for thinking of me" note might not be a bad idea just so they know not to expect any other response.

Comment: I was told to do this for my Ph.D thesis (which I did in Canada) and I didn't do it. :|

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with the OP's view that a copy of the original paper(s) derived from the thesis work (obtainable from the publishing journal) would be adequate. Before digital photography these were needed in order for any micrographs, etc in the paper to be as clear as possible. Nowadays with full digital publishing of images, it should be less of a problem. If the requester needs more detail of the research, sure they can ask for a copy of your thesis via inter-library loans and suchlike. As to what to do with the hardcopy: just return it with a tactfully warm note.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is not uncommon in the country where I did my PhD (the Netherlands). There you have to print a reasonably large amount of hardcopies anyway, typically people get around 200-300 copies in my field. It is not uncommon to send some copies to researchers that you genuinely believe may be interested in the work, usually people that you have been in contact with before, or are in contact with your advisor.

The cost of the thesis printing and mailing is generally reimbursed by the university (of course, all within reasonable limits). In countries where printing the thesis is not so common, I can imagine that the practice of mailing around copies is not common.

Comment: I definitely come from a different tradition. It cost almost 200 USD to print the five soft-cover comb-bound copies of my thesis (needed some pages printed in color) for my committee. I cannot imagine the cost of printing and distributing hundreds of copies of the approved thesis.

Comment: It can be done quite cheaply these days. I paid about 6 euros per book for 200 copies, with full colour cover and b/w text. It was a glued soft-cover though, so not for too heavy use (which is OK I suppose for a thesis).

Comment: Two hundred copies is *not* "reasonable."

Comment: @BenNorris $40 for a comb-bound document with a few colour pages?!? That sounds extortionate. I printed my thesis on the department's printers (which would have done colour if I'd needed it) at the cost only of buying myself some nicer paper than standard copier paper. I don't know what comb-binding would have cost but we had a machine for available for general use for nothing. Even without access to a comb-binder to do it yourself, I can't believe that a copy-shop would charge more than a couple of dollars.

Comment: Yes, the graduate was from VU Amsterdam, so I guess that is indeed common. I was completely unaware that they literally print hundrets of theses there. I guess it makes sense that I might be among the 200 most related researchers to the guy, FWIW :) where I graduated, we usually print 5 to 10 copies, at costs northern of 25 USD per copy.

Comment: @aeismail 200 copies appeared to be around the normal amount in the Netherlands, at least as far as I am aware. Of these already a sizable number (50 or so) go to libraries, the thesis committee, etc. And then it's commonn to give the other students a copy, all faculty, etc, so it adds up quite quickly.

Comment: A number around 200 is the norm in Sweden and as far as I can see in Norway, Denmark and Finland as well. I think aeismail comment is premature and unfortunately lacking insight. What is "reasonable" will depend on the system.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I got the b/w pages for free from my department, but I had to go to Kinkos for the color pages and binding. And that explains the cost.

Comment: I agree with Peter Jansson's last comment: I don't see the point in participating in this site without a spirit of openness about the rich variety of academic practices across different disciplines and locations.  What is "reasonable" for one group will not be so for another: we should not be so quick to criticize.

Comment: What on earth does this typically cost, and for a quantity of 200 isn't it a flagrant waste of research money? Guessing at least $1-2000 with printing, binding and postage. PDF sounds better (unless impossible for copyright reasons).

Comment: "It can be done quite cheaply these days. I paid about 6 euros per book for 200 copies, with full colour cover and b/w text." So you paid about 1200 euros? That's a full order of magnitude more than my printing costs were, and I complained about them at the time! I mean, yeah, I guess I can see the point in it, in terms of actually getting your thesis read by more people. But .pdf sounds a much better way to achieve that these days to me.

Comment: The Dutch/Swedish/European(?) system is essentially publication on a small scale. (It's not selective but since it's standard practice, I wouldn't call it a vanity press either.) I got my degree in the US and believe me, it's much nicer to hold a glossy glue-bound volume than the typical copy shop fare that passes as "hard copy" in the US.

Comment: Like I said, you need about 50 copies minimum to fulfill the requirements. Since for these volumes the startup cost of the printing press are the major part, printing 100 or 200 copies does actually not increase the price by that much. And as mentioned, it is usually reimbursed by the university. (In addition, PhD students are paid employees). These days of course digital versions are also available on e.g. the library website, but most universities still require you to print the thesis as well.

Comment: Man, I five copies of my thesis made and thought that was excessive.

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens: From a German point of view, the most surprising part about this is not that you have to print several dozen to a few hundred hardcopies, but that you get reimbursed for them instead of paying out of your own pocket ;)

Comment: Wow! I was not aware that this practice existed in some places. I believe exactly one copy of my PhD thesis was printed. It is held by the university library in off-site storage. I never saw it. All I did was pay the library US$37 and give them the pdf.

Answer (score 34):

In some countries you print a large number of copies (as stated by Pieter Naaijkens), in some only a single digit number which should then be distributed to a specific set of recipients. Regardless it is not unusual that a person might distribute copies to people that might have some interest in it. It is, however, not a must and the recipients is up to the author. When you send a thesis I think it is wise to write an accompanying letter explaining why the thesis is sent to the specific person. To send them without such a personal note may come across as a little odd and can of course be misunderstood.

I did my PhD in the US and made a larger number of cheap copies (do not remember how many) to distribute among friends. I sent a few to others whose research I had built on. This was outside of the, at least then, mandatory five bound copies. In Sweden, where I now reside, printing of about 250 is mandatory and the student can print additional copies at their own cost. We recommend students to think about sending their thesis to people they can imagine would be interested in it. Since the life time of a thesis is usually quite short, most will soon be properly published, it is a good way to advertise your PhD and your work right after you have completed the work.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a covering letter. Had the grad in the OP's example done that, OP would have been much less confused.

Answer (score 20):

I have, so far as I can remember, physical copies of three PhD theses that were not written by my own students.  (I do not have a physical copy of my own PhD thesis.)  Two of these were indeed PhDs from the Netherlands, where they bind the theses in an attractive way and clearly send them out rather broadly.  One of them is from an older student in my department, whose work was very influential to me.

I have certainly been happy to have all of these theses.  The one from the student in my department I have certainly consulted at length.   The other two less so, but a colleague of mine once borrowed it (and then duly returned it).  I am not aware that any of these three theses are freely available on the internet, so it is not purely an empty gesture.

> Last week I by chance got hold of the graduate and told him that he sent me his thesis by accident, and asked whether he wants to have it back. He seemed confused and a little bit annoyed that I wanted to give his thesis back - it turns out he actually sent me the book on purpose, assuming that I would be interested in his work.

As you've probably realized by now, your behavior was a bit rude.  What are the chances that someone sent you a PhD thesis by accident??  Offering to give back something that someone sends you without first inquiring into the circumstances in which they sent it is really not great behavior.  When someone gives something to you -- in circumstances other than a bribe or some similar kind of implicit *quid pro quo* -- the polite thing to do is say "Thank you."  It would be a classy move to apologize to the person whose thesis you tried to give back.

Comment: Why is it the OP's fault for not knowing the author's cultural custom? If anything, I would think it is the author's fault for not taking into account that not everyone follows *his* culture's custom of mailing theses.

Comment: @AustinHenley The funny thing is that I live 90 airplane minutes away from Amsterdam, so you would think that the "culture clash" would be minimal, but I was in fact completely unaware of this custom (but I do agree with Pete L. Clark that an apology from me is probably in order the next time we meet).

Comment: @Austin: I don't think this is an interesting instance of a "cultural custom": that would rather be an instance in which one is apparently being given something but is not actually supposed to keep it.  In general, the idea that when someone gives you something, they meant to do it and want you to accept it seems rather "globally standard".  Anyway, it's not really a matter of **fault**: obviously the OP did not intend to offend the person who gave him his thesis, and it seems like he did, a little bit.  So an apology is probably in order.  It doesn't mean anyone did anything so terrible...

Comment: I disagree with the last paragraph. When someone gives something to you that, to the best of your knowledge, is probably not intended for you, accepting it is actually quite rude, bordering on theft. The polite thing in that situation is to show humility and do what you should do when something "falls off the truck" - you give it back rather than assuming it was a gift. But then, maybe that is a cultural difference once again, thus this comes back to @AustinHenley's comment.

Answer (score 6):

This varies by country and probably by field as well, which means I can only speak from my own experience in physics, in the US. What my experience says is that it is exceptionally rare to do this. Typically, a student will have one copy of their thesis printed and bound for their adviser, one for themselves, one or two for the university library if required by policy, and perhaps one or two for the student's parents, if they're interested. Each one of these copies costs $50 or more, and costs are borne by the student, so there is a large incentive to print as few copies as necessary.

More recently (in the past few years), I believe a lot of universities have switched to electronic archival of theses, which means the campus library no longer requires a printed copy. In these cases, a finalized PhD thesis might never get printed at all, depending on the preferences of the student and the adviser.

Certainly, to me, it is unheard of to send unsolicited printed copies of the thesis to other researchers. Of course, in physics some PhD theses are uploaded to [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) for electronic distribution, so interested researchers can get access to them that way.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it could be of interest that in some countries of Central and Eastern Europe there exists a tradition of sending to many places in the country where the Ph.D. studies are done (especially major libraries and universities) not the full Ph.D. thesis but the so-called thesis summary ("autoreferat"). The sending is usually done by the institution where the Ph.D. studies are done and takes place *before* the viva, so that, at least in theory, the interested parties may visit the viva and ask the questions to the author of the thesis.

Answer (score 3):

I sent printed copies of my thesis to the people I mentioned in the acknowledgment section. That is about 20 persons. I obviously didn't think they would read it, and in fact the content was already obsolete at the time it went through the printer, it was more of a way of marking the event, and well, letting them know that I thanked them in my preamble.

I would not be surprised, however, that someone would get puzzled if I sent them a copy and they had no direct tie to my work. I mean, I don't send pdfs of my articles to people I think would be interested in reading them...

Answer (score -1):

Totally uncommon to me. I'm doing my PhD thesis and if I were that student, I'd send first an email asking whether there is an interest or not. In any case, I'd not expect that someone will read my thesis (book) just for fun or because *that might interest you*. Even PhD supervisors complain reading PhD theses that look like books!